# Irregular behavior in C physics program

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to put together a simple physics engine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Vector
{
    double x, y;
} Vector;

const double GRAVITY  = 0.1;
const double FRICTION = 0.9;

typedef struct RigidBody
{
    Vector*  pos;
    Vector*  vel;
    Vector*  acc;
    uint16_t mass;
} RigidBody;

void addForce(RigidBody* body, double x, double y)
{
    body->acc->x += x / body->mass;
    body->acc->y += y / body->mass;
}
void updateRigidBody(RigidBody* body)
{
    addForce(body, 0, GRAVITY * body->mass);
    
    body->vel->x += body->acc->x;
    body->vel->y += body->acc->y;
    
    body->vel->x *= FRICTION;
    body->vel->y *= FRICTION;
    
    body->pos->x += body->vel->x;
    body->pos->y += body->vel->y;
    
    body->acc->x = 0;
    body->acc->y = 0;
}
void resetRigidBody(RigidBody* body, double x, double y)
{
    body->pos->x = x;
    body->pos->y = y;
    
    body->vel->x = 0;
    body->vel->y = 0;
    
    body->acc->x = 0;
    body->acc->y = 0;
}

struct
{
    RigidBody body;
} Player;

void initPlayer(double x, double y)
{
    Player.body = (RigidBody)
    {
        &((Vector) {x, y}),
        &((Vector) {0, 0}),
        &((Vector) {0, 0}),
        10,
    };
}
void updatePlayer()
{
    updateRigidBody(&Player.body);
}
void resetPlayer(double x, double y)
{
    resetRigidBody(&Player.body, x, y);
}

int main()
{
    initPlayer(10, 10);
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            updatePlayer();
        }
    }
    printf("%g", Player.body.pos->y);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not print the expected result, and instead prints 0.99. I tried to diagnose it by printing the rigidbody's Y speed after updating it, by adding this after line 42:

```
    printf("%g\n", body->vel->y);
```

Unfortunately, that actually changed the result:

```
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
0.99
4.16586e-312
```

This would seem to suggest a memory problem possibly caused by undefined behavior, but looking at my code everything seems regular, and my compiler did not issue any warnings; I also avoided allocating any memory (e.g. using malloc), and relied on the stack. What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: You're setting `Player.body` to the addresses of values that no longer exist after `InitPlayer()` returns

Comment: Any reason to have pointers?  Why not just have Vectors in RigidBody?

Comment: @JohnBollinger   Oooops!  I misread the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
Player.body = (RigidBody)
{
    &((Vector) {x, y}),
    &((Vector) {0, 0}),
    &((Vector) {0, 0}),
    10,
};
```

there are compound literals at block scope, which means their lifetime ends after the current block. When the function returns, the object `body` contains dangling pointers.

It would be much simpler to just not use pointers:

```
typedef struct RigidBody
{
    Vector pos, vel, acc;
    uint16_t mass;
} RigidBody;
```

// ...

```
Player.body = (RigidBody)
{
    .pos.x = x,
    .pos.y = y,
    .mass = 10
};
```